# "tomorrow is not a promised" correctnesss

Tags: expressions

Is it a correct expression? Seems to figure in quotes but I can't find a decent source in regards to correctness.

Comment: This models on the nounification in 'It's a given'. Where have you checked for a noun usage of 'promised'?

Comment: What quotes have you found this figuring in?  You can't simply allude to sources; you must cite them.

Comment: @Spencer Pretty much bad motivational quotes online. Saw it on a shirt and a discussion started IRL as to whether it is correct or not. Googled the quote itself and it exists online but I got none of the usual dict sites in the search, hence the lack of a decent source

Comment: It makes no sense to me. It is missing an object or has an extra article or something.  I would not use it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not "grammatical" in the sense that it would be accepted in widespread use.

Having Googled around a bit, I've convinced myself that this is some sort of religious formula or [shibboleth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth), and a recent one at that.

Religious formulas often adopt unusual constructions for their primary purpose of separating in-group from out-group.

Indeed, the earliest reference I can find is in a 2012 religious tract,  *[The Transforming Believer](https://books.google.com/books?id=7eh72zyyk7YC&pg=PA13&dq=%22tomorrow+is+not+a-promised%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCkNPJx-DmAhWLl-AKHY9NBt0Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22tomorrow%20is%20not%20a-promised%22&f=false)* by Zulibe Turner of Reading, UK.

> Time waits for no body, and tomorrow is not a promised to anyone.

Whether this is intentional, or a typo that got through proofreading, is not apparent. I also noticed an unusual use of "no body" for "nobody".

Edwin Ashworth and Colin Fine suggest that this formation is a deliberate neologism, along the lines of "a given", and this may very well be, but there are other possibilities including simple error.

The apparent error in this phrase is the use of the article "a" with "promised". "Promised" is almost never used as a noun - the only time I have encountered it is 19th-century costume dramas where "my promised" was a synonym for "my betrothed".

More common uses of "promised" are as a verb (*You promised me*) or as an adjective (*the promised land*)

So we might more commonly say

> Tomorrow is not a promised *day*

(which appeared more frequently in religious quotes during my search)

Or of course we can use "promise" as a noun:

> Tomorrow is not a promise

But Ms Turner's phrasing does not fit either of these patterns; she says tomorrow is not "a promised to ***anyone***". Assuming this was intentional and not a mistake, the only way I can resolve it is to claim the word "a" is not an article here - it's an archaic prefix, sometimes attached to to a word (*he lay abed*) or but often hyphenated (*Simple Simon went a-fishing, for to catch a whale*).

One use of the "a-" prefix is to mean "completely".  This would give us

> Tomorrow is not **a-promised** to anyone

and would be grammatical, if unusual.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, as Edwin Ashworth says, that it's a deliberate neologism, consciously modelled on _a given_.

Comment: @ColinFine Perhaps...that would put it more firmly into the "shibboleth" column in my estimation.

Comment: Maybe. I was confused, because I've never met that meaning of _shibboleth_. But I'm dubious: I think it is intended to be understood, and to confront the reader with a new understanding.

Comment: @ColinFine Needless to say, I don't see what nounizing "promised" adds to an already profound statement. It's just putting a hat on a hat. Darn, I wish I could wear two Winter Bash hats at once.